# How to configure two Mathematica in different places with different settings

Tags: front-end

For some reasons, I should use two language versions *Mathematica*.

The most reason is I want to see the comparison of Help page(English version and Chinese version) to improve my English, both are useful.

- [update]However, When I just concentrate on the language of Help page, that problem is nothing, just put english help page in the english version, and chinese help page in the chinese version, open Mathematica by two shortcut, it's OK now, ignore the language of the UI(both Chinese).

### question 1:

How to make `FrontEnd` do not show this popup dialogue?

[image]

### question2:

I've installed two *Mathematica* 9 with different language versions.

One in Disk D `English` Version

One in Disk E `ChineseSimplified` Version

How to configure two different settings?

## *(Hard point:)*

Because they share the configures, some configure files are stored here in my computer.

```
"E:\\Users\\Quaternions\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica"
"E:\\Users\\Quaternions\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\FrontEnd\\init.m"
```

How to make the different configures, such as `Language`, `Background` and others.

For background color, the value of `Background` is easy to setting.
As I've tried, one can add

```
SetOptions[FrontEndSession,Background->LightBlue]
```

in some init.m

here

```
"D:\\Program Files\\Wolfram\\Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\SystemFiles\\Autoload\\PacletManager\\Kernel\\init.m"
```

or here

```
"D:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\AddOns\\AutoLoad\\English\\init.m"
```

And then when open *Mathematica* in Disk D, the background is LightBlue.

When open *Mathematica* in Disk E, the background will be White ($FrontEnd background value).

What's the tough thing?
The value of `$Language`

So the keypoint of the problem is：
How to open *Mathematica* in Disk D whose `$Language` is English [Help page language is English, and also UI is English], and Open *Mathematica* in Disk E whose `$Language` is ChineseSimplifed [Help page language is ChineseSimplified and also UI is ChineseSimplified]

Comment: Are they the same version of different?  If they're the same version, why would you install it twice?  You can run two instances without installing it twice.

Comment: Maybe you can edit the corresponding registry entries to redirect one of the folders.

Comment: @HyperGroups Why can't you just run two instances of the same instead of installing it twice?  It doesn't seem to make sense what you're doing.

Comment: @Szabolcs Two instances of Mathematica is ok, but the pop-up dialogue of language settings is annoying.

Comment: Hypergroups are you the only user of these two versions if I may ask? Do they have the same `$UserBaseDirectory`?

Comment: Hypergroups, did you solve this yet?

Comment: @Jocob hi, forgot to respond, I haven't solved this.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Yes, I'm the only user, they have the same $UserBaseDirectory, that's annoying thing.

Comment: Hypergroups, check out [ref/program/Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/Mathematica.html), maybe you can use a command line argument to specify where to look for preferences.

Answer (score 1):

The (some?) front end settings are stored here (most likely on all platforms)

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd", "init.m"}]
```

This is a user specific directory. This enables you to have different settings for different users.

If I set the option `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DynamicUpdating-> False]` the corresponding value in this file changes. When I restart Mathematica, the value will be the same.

I would expect the same behaviour to occur if you change the setting `Language -> Automatic` into something else. However I am a bit hesitant to perform tests on this. Have you tried this?

Comment: However, When I just concentrate on the language of Help page, that problem is nothing, just put english help page in the english version, and chinese help page in the chinese version, open Mathematica by two shortcut, it's OK now, ignore the language of the UI(both Chinese).